# Custom button with top and bottom margin

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-button

I need to create a layout like below.

[image: android]

And I worked out how to create a this layout:

[image: android]

How can I add top and bottom margins?  And button background color?  I made the button transparent by using:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Now how can I make button background color to light blue.

If I use custom button layout, how can I do that?  I checked lots of Stackoverflow questions, but all of them concern gradient, color change on click, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: why you won't try to make a square botton with photshop fill it with transparent blue that you desire and after that add white border up and down. we developer have to be designer some times :D

Comment: i forget make this png file that you save a 9 patch image after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use the *transparent* background color ... instead set it to the blue color you want.  Then use *setAlpha* to make it partially transparent:

```
MyButton.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
```

To set both the border and transparent background, I think you'll have to make an XML drawable and define as the button's background:

```
android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbackground"
```

Then the drawable resource should be like this (/res/drawable/mybuttonbackground.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

   <item android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp"> 
        <shape ="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thank you! And how I make top and bottom lines?

Comment: @lsuru updated my answer.  I think the only way is to use a *Drawable* for the background.

Comment: Thank you very much you are the best! If you can, leave me a good link where I can learn more about custom layouts.

Comment: @Isuru Sweet!  Glad it worked for you.  I think the Android developer site is a great resource to read up on.  It's not too dry and has lots of examples.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html